# How to escape a symbol (not string) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, struct, escaping

I'm creating a web crawler with Ruby and Mechanize. The web site that I'm crawling is sending this kind of POST data with square brackets. The problem is that Mechanize uses struct and I haven't found a way to escape the square brackets in a struct key:

```
   post_body = {
       data[User][username]: username,
       data[User][password]: password,
       data[selector]: 1
   }
```

I've tried to put the keys inside strings, and to use this kind of syntax:

```
post_body = Struct.new(#{data[User][username]}, #{data[User][password]}, #{data[selector]})
post_body.new(username, password, 1)
```

but I get an error:

```
identifier data[User][username] needs to be constant
```

Comment: Please post how the data from the site looks _exactly_. It should be a string in the first place.

Comment: Not entirely sure I get your question, but what you probably want is `data[User][username] => username` instead of `data[User][username]: username`.

Answer (score 0):

To make what @ndenkov already said more explicit:

If you have a hash

```
{ foo: 4711 }
```

this is just syntactic sugar for

```
{ :foo => 4711 }
```

This means that the key must syntactically be a simple symbol, basically following the same syntax as an identifier.